# Diagnosing why a mac needs safe mode to boot

Tags: snow-leopard, imac, startup, macos

"Fresh" install of snow leopard 10.6 needs safe mode to boot. It's a 2006 24" iMac and I can't upgrade the software to lion since it's not availiable on app store (I don't really want to shell out any money on it if I can help it) and the other OS's are too new to run on it. I've fully updated the computer but I have to hold shift to start it up otherwise it just loads to a white screen.

Is there anyway I can find any sort of information on what is causing this. Are startup errors logged anywhere that I can go into afterwards, or is there any sort of diagnostics I can run?

Apple have given up on it, but I haven't! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem with 10.6 is that safari is way to out of date to be useful. Have you considered running Windows 10? You may laugh, but the computer I am using right now is a mid 2007 iMac running Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I appreciate the feedback but I'd rather stick chrome on it and be done with it.